# Onload Multiple Dynamic Images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
function LoadPage (page) {
// each page contains 10 pictures
    var endp = page*10;
// Empty the main container that contains the pictures
    $('#container').empty();
// Rewrite the Page Menu
    for (j=1;j<Math.abs(len/10);j++) {
        $('#container').append("<a href='javascript: LoadData("+j+")'>"+j+"</a>");
    }
// Add the image containers containing images
    for (i=endp-10;i<endp;i++) {
            $('#container').append("<div class='container' id="+i+" >");
    $('#'+i).append("<img src="+x[i].getElementsByTagName('URL')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue+" width='200'>");
        $('#container').append("</div>");
    }
// Have to call a function ' wall.reload(); ' once all the pictures are loaded!
    setTimeout(function(){
    if (wall) { wall.reload(); }
            },2000);
}
```

This function is called multiple times, each time with a page number. Everything is working fine. I am using a setTimeout() function to delay the function wall.reload() but I don't want to do that. Rather I want the function to wait till all the images are load and then fire wall.reload()

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an onload attribute to your image tag. 
There you would call a function such as imageLoaded(), which increments an imageCounter. If the imagecounter matches the amount of images you added it would call the wall.reload(). Code could look somewhat similair to the following:

```
var imagesLoaded = 0;
function imageLoaded(){
  imagesLoaded++
  if(imagesLoaded == numberOfImages)
    wall.reload();
  }
}
```

And in the image tag:

```
<img src="asdf.jpg" onload="imageLoaded()">
```

Comment: thanks alot Michael. It worked. However a new issue is raised now. Once I $('#con').empty() the main container and add new .conainter to the main container, the inherent jQuery events on .container such as click and hover stop working. Its a weird behavior. Any idea?

Comment: If you remove a DOM Element, it loses all it's events. By just inserting a new Element in the DOM, even with the same class, you wont automatically get the click handlers. You have to call the function that adds the event handlers again after you inserted the new content.

Answer (score 0):

```
function LoadPage (page) {
// each page contains 10 pictures
    var endp = page*10;
    // Empty the main container that contains the pictures
    $('#container').empty();
    // Rewrite the Page Menu
    for (j=1;j<Math.abs(len/10);j++) {
        $('#container').append("<a href='javascript: LoadData("+j+")'>"+j+"</a>");
    }

    // count of the loaded images
    var counterLoaded = 0;
    function waitReload(){
       counterLoaded++;
       // if all 10 images loaded
       if (counterLoaded == 10){
          if (wall){
             wall.reload();
          }
       }
    }

    // Add the image containers containing images
    for (i=endp-10;i<endp;i++) {
        $('#container').append("<div class='container' id="+i+" >");
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = x[i].getElementsByTagName('URL')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        img.setAttribute('width', '200');
        $('#'+i).append(img);
        $('#container').append("</div>");
        // if image loaded - increment loaded images counter
        img.onload = waitReload;
    }
 }
```